# What are the exceptions to Special Triplets for Right Triangles?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, triangles

I was working on a right triangle problem which had the following two measurements for two of its legs - 8 and 10.

I immediately thought special right triplet: 3-4-5. However, the answer stated that was incorrect and that leveraging pythagarus theorem - I would get the correct missing side measurement which was approx 13.

I just want to confirm that the special right triplets we learned in school only hold when the largest triplet is appropriately assigned to the hypotenuse otherwise it would violate the rule of two sides in a right triangle have to always be greater than the missing side? Thank you so much!

[image]

Comment: No exception here.  In any triangle, the longest side is opposite the largest angle.  In a right triangle, the hypotenuse must be the longest side.  In the $6-8-10$ right triangle, the $10$ must be the length of the hypotenuse.

Comment: Thank you so much @lulu!! Just needed to confirm that :)

Comment: It seems like this is an online test, can you provide a link?

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  Pythagorean theorem states that
$$a^2 + b^2 = c^2$$
where $a$ and $b$ are the lengths of the *legs* of the right triangle, while $c$ is the length of the *hypotenuse*.

Now, what information are you given in the problem?  What unknown are you required to find?

Comment: The question was asking to find the missing side - which was the hypotenuse. I was given basically the side lengths of two legs which looked like they formed the right triangle triplet 8-10. But in this case this doesn't apply bc as @lulu said only works when largest side has the largest triplet assigned to it.

Comment: Yes, indeed that is correct.